# Adding new objects to list and showing them

Tags: clojure

i started learning clojure and i got stuck with this thing,i have a knowledge of java and maybe my approach is too java-like but my real question is-i made a function that lets the user type a few strings,now i want when user enters those strings to make a new object and then insert it into a list so i can show the elements of that list later,how can it be done?i tried...

```
(defn unesi []

   (println "Unesite ime i prezime studenta: ")

   (let [imePrezime (read-line)]
     (println "Unesite index studenta: ")
      (let [index (read-line)]
         (println "Unesite email studenta: ")
         (let [email (read-line)]
          (def s1 {:ime imePrezime :index index :email email})
           (println "Uspjesno ste unijeli studenta!")
         )

       )

   )

   )
```

i have managed to make a new object but it is always the same one,how can i always add a new one?and how to add it to a list to show elements later?

Comment: Shile, @GuillermoWinkler's answer addresses your specific question, after remarking that your example might not be the right one to start with.  But in another sense, it might be a good place to start, if you look at it differently.  Maybe you don't need for the same object to change.  In Clojure it often makes sense to throw away a data structure that's no longer needed, and create a new one.  That can be easier.  Once consequence of Clojure's emphasis on immutable data structures in order to support efficient use of multiple processors is that mutable data structures are harder to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you're starting with clojure with the *right* example. Clojure [favors immutability](http://clojure.org/state), and you're trying just to mutate something.

None the less, addressing your question.

1. I'm using [an atom](http://clojure.org/atoms) `students` for the list state between function calls.
2. I defined a local function `read-input` which prints the input message then reads the line for a little reuse.
3. Each new `student` gets [conjed](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/conj) into the existent `students` list, and the list gets swaped with the new one.

Code:

```
 (def students (atom []))

 (defn unesi []
    (letfn [(read-input [message]
            (println message)
            (read-line))]
     (let [imePrezime (read-input "Unesite ime i prezime studenta: ")
           index (read-input "Unesite index studenta: ")
           email (read-input "Unesite email studenta: ")]
         (swap! students #(conj % {:ime imePrezime :index index :email email}))
         (println "Uspjesno ste unijeli studenta!"))))
```

You can then access the list using the [deref](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/deref) operator `@`

```
user> @students
  =>  [{:ime "guille", :index "3", :email "guille@email"} 
       {:ime "cacho", :index "pedro", :email "lala"}]
```